# Am i able to drag an element that is outside of the iframe into iframe using cypress?

Tags: iframe, drag-and-drop, cypress

[image]

require('@4tw/cypress-drag-drop')

describe('Test', function() {

```
before(function () {

it('Creating template', function() {

    cy.visit ('my_website')

    cy
    .get('#elementor-panel-category-animated_sections > .elementor-panel-category-items > :nth-child(3) > .elementor-element > .elementor-element-title-wrapper > .URL')
    .drag('#elementor-add-new-section > div > div.elementor-add-new-section > div.elementor-add-section-area-button.elementor-add-section-button')  
});
```

})
})

Comment: Is this a public website, If yes can you share the URL?

Answer (score 0):

If your target is inside an iframe, where is your iframe code in the test?

Please read Cypress blog [Working with iframes in Cypress](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/02/12/working-with-iframes-in-cypress/) on how to access elements inside an iframe, or post sufficient HTML that someone can do it for you.

General pattern is

```js
cy.visit(...)
cy.frameLoaded('[data-cy="the-frame"]')
cy.iframe().find('#my-drop-target')
  .then($el => $el[0].getBoundingClientRect())
  .then(targetBox => {

    cy.get(sourceSelector)
      .then($el => $el[0].getBoundingClientRect())
      .then(sourceBox => {

        const deltaX = targetBox.x - sourceBox.x
        const deltaY = targetBox.y - sourceBox.y

        cy.get(sourceSelector)
          .trigger('mousedown', { which: 1 })
          .trigger('mousemove', { clientX: deltaX, clientY: deltaY })
          .trigger('mouseup', { force: true })
       })
})
```